# How to convert DER formatted public key file to PEM form

Tags: unix, public-key, rsa

I need to use the PEM formatted public key for some purpose, but not finding the command which can convert DER formatted public key to PEM formatted public key.

The command I have used -
`openssl rsa -in user_id_rsa.pub -inform DER -outform PEM -out pubkey.pem`

Actually the command expect private key as a input.
But I got the below error -

> unable to load Private Key 139901900170912:error:0D0680A8:asn1
>   encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1337:
>   139901900170912:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:677:
>   139901900170912:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1337:
>   139901900170912:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:388:Type=RSA

My expected output should be in this format-

> -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
>        **KEY CONTENT**
>   -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

Has anyone tried the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add `-pubin` for public key inputs.

```
openssl rsa -pubin -in user_id_rsa.pub -inform DER -outform PEM -out pubkey.pem
```

EDIT: To handle PEM `RSA PUBLIC KEY` format, specify `-RSAPublicKey_in` `-RSAPublicKey_out` instead.

```
openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -in user_id_rsa.pub -inform DER -outform PEM -out pubkey.pem -RSAPublicKey_out
```

If you want to convert OpenSSH public key to PEM `RSA PUBLIC KEY`, just use `ssh-keygen`.

```
ssh-keygen -f user_id_rsa.pub -e -m PEM > pubkey.pem
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs..But i got the following error -  
unable to load Public Key  
139731637118624:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1337:  
139731637118624:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:388:Type=X509_PUBKEY

Comment: Is `user_id_rsa.pub` really an RSA public key in DER format?  How did you generate that file?  OpenSSH public key format is not DER.

Comment: Please check updates in my answer.

Comment: @CodeQuestor, Accept this answer if this solved your question.